# How do I run a virsh command as an administrator before the window manager starts?

Tags: sudo, startup, kvm-virtualization

I need to run the following command BEFORE my window manager starts

```
sudo virsh nodedev-detach pci_0000_05_00_0
```

It must be run as an administrator, and it must be run before the window manager loads.

I'm currently using the following script to achieve my goal in the terminal view for my Kubuntu 20.04 operating system:

```
#!/bin/sh
systemctl stop sddm.service
virsh nodedev-detach pci_0000_05_00_0
systemctl start sddm.service
```

This is so that the vfio-pci driver can take over from nvidia for my second GPU in my kvm vfio setup as nothing else I have tried has worked. Switching into a terminal and running these three commands is jarring, and often causes issues with my window manager once it's reloaded.

How do I run a script with administrative permissions before my desktop environment loads?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem.

In order to force a driver for VFIO to unbind from nvidia  BEFORE the startup of the window manager, you must edit your Xsetup script (For me, it was at /usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup) and add the following to the end of the file:

```
virsh nodedev-detach pci_0000_05_00_0
```

It worked flawlessly. However, at that point in the startup, the program did not bind vfio-pci to the device, and that had to be done manually.

However, I found that an easier solution to my problem was to download driverctl and run

```
sudo driverctl set-override 0000:05:00.0 vfio-pci
```

THIS finally forced the kernel to bind my second GPU to the vfio-pci driver instead of my nvidia driver. The command MUST be run in terminal mode (CTRL + AlT + 2), and you must stop your window manager (For KUBUNTU sudo systemctl stop sddm.service). Don't bother turning it back on, just reboot. This prevents nvidia from binding to the device, and forced vfio-pci to bind.